# Do you lose the reserved space in a Qt string with the QString::clear() function?

Tags: qt, memory-management

I am working on a loop where I want to copy a few characters from a string to another. I know the limit is around 20 characters so I want to do this outside the loop:

```
QString name;
name.reserve(25);
```

That way I have a buffer ready to be filled and Qt avoids reallocating it every time a name is parsed. Only, to get the name I do something like this:

```
for(int i(0); i < 20 && *s != '\0'; ++i)
{
    name += *s;
}
```

which means I have to reset the name each time. How can I do that and be sure that the reserved space doesn't get lost every time?

```
// will reserved memory be lost after this call?
name.clear();

// would that be more likely to keep the memory buffer?
name = "";
```

The documentation does not seem to say one way or the other.

The complete set of loops goes something like this:

```
QString name;
name.reserve(25);

for(QChar const *s(input.data()); *s != '\0'; ++s)
{
    ...snip...
    if(<some condition>)
    {
        name.clear() // losing reserved data here?
        for(int i(0); i < 20 && *s != '\0'; ++i)
        {
            name += *s;
        }
        ...snip...
    }
    ...snip...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `name.clear()` will clear internal buffer but `name += ...` certainly will not do that. It's not clear from your question if you actually need to preserve buffer through `clear()` or you for some reason think that `+=` has the same effect as `clear()`.

Comment: The `.clear()` is what  I'm wondering about. The loop doing the `+=` is inside another loop so I'd like to keep the reserved buffer each time the loop with the `name += *s;` is hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `QString::clear()` will cause your reserved space to be lost.  Consider the following:

```
QString s;
s.reserve(25);
qDebug() << "Before Clear: " << s.capacity();
s.clear();
qDebug() << "After Clear: " << s.capacity();
```

Output:

```
Before Clear: 25
After Clear: 0
```

The most efficient way to remove the contents of the string without losing your reserved space is to call `QString::resize()`:

```
QString s;
s.reserve(25);
qDebug() << "Before Resize: " << s.capacity();
s.resize(0);
qDebug() << "After Resize: " << s.capacity();
```

Output:

```
Before Resize: 25
After Resize: 25
```

In the implementation of `QString::resize()`, a call to `resize(0)` for strings with reserved capacity amounts to setting the internal size value to `0` and setting the first character of the internal buffer to `'\0'`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the QString::truncate(int pos) method might be a better option  than resize in this case because it strictly shortens a string, and is clearer / more readable (at least to me). Like resize, it does not affect the QString capacity according to my quick test.